# is that right for bind the data from the mvvm concept to the xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to get the output from the database by using the mvvm concept. But, the output is not coming correctly. Values are stored to the variable but not binding what can i to do?

```
<StackPanel Margin="5" 
            DataContext="{Binding Path=LocationListModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
         <Label Content="Location Name"/>
         <ComboBox Name="cmbLocation" 
               Width="200" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding LocationList}" 
               DisplayMemberPath="LocationName"  
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedString}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: What is the data context of this view? post the code of `LocationListModel`. Also where does the `LocationListModel` comes from? What is the base data context? How `LocationList` and `SelectedString` properties are defined? Also refer output window of visual studio for binding errors.

Comment: thank you for your care. i solved my self thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just remove the datacontext in XAML

```
  **

<StackPanel Margin="5">
         <Label Content="Location Name"/>
         <ComboBox Name="cmbLocation" 
               Width="200" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding LocationList}" 
               DisplayMemberPath="LocationName"  
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedString}"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

**

then just cal the view model from the c# Code
 like

```
 LocationListModel loc=new LocationViewModel();
//Constructer()
 this.DataContext=loc;
//
```